# Someone came up with a word I want to know about in ekadashi

Tags: sita, ekadashi

There is this message going on

> " *परिवर्तिनी एकादशी व्रत* 
>  *डोल ग्यारस व्रत*  
>  *पदमा एकादशी व्रत* 
>  *जल झूलनी एकादशी व्रत*

> *कल सुबह 7:55 से लेकर परसो मंगलवार प्रातः 5:00 मिनट तक एकादशी है....* ....

> *विशेष एकादशी का व्रत मंगलवार, 26 सितंबर 2023 द्वादशी से जुड़ी एकादशी का ही व्रत करें ... एवं कल और परसों पूरे दिन खाने में चावल या चावल से बनी हुई चीज वस्तु का प्रयोग बिल्कुल भी ना करें*

> *आइए अब जानते हैं कि एकादशी व्रत कल नहीं और परसों  26 सितंबर 2023, मंगलवार को ही क्यों❓*

> पद्मपुराण में एक प्रसंग है जब भगवान वाराह और हिरण्याक्ष का युद्ध हो रहा था तब भगवान नारायण के बार बार कोशिश करने पर भी जब हिरण्याक्ष नहीं मर रहा था तब भगवान ब्रह्मा जी ने भगवान नारायण से पूछा हे प्रभु यह असुर तो आपकी दृष्टि मात्र से मरना चाहिए ऐसा क्यों हो रहा है कि आप इसे मार नहीं पा रहे हैं ❓

> तब प्रभु श्री नारायण बोले ब्रह्मा जी *शुक्राचार्य की माया से मोहित होने से कुछ ब्राह्मण दशमी युक्ता एकादशी का व्रत कर रहे हैं*

> क्योंकि दशमी के दिन दैत्यों की उत्पत्ति हुई थी और *एकादशी के दिन देवताओं की उत्पत्ति हुई थी* इसीलिए *दशमी से जुड़ी हुई एकादशी का व्रत करने से दैत्यों का बल बढ़ता है* और *इसी दिन एकादशी का व्रत करने से देवताओं का बल बढ़ता है* ब्राह्मणों के दशमी विद्धा एकादशी का व्रत करने से दैत्य का बल बढ़ रहा है और यह मर नहीं रहा है

> *जो मनुष्य दशमी युक्ता एकादशी का व्रत करता है उसके अंदर आसुरी  शक्ति बढ़ती है ।* { *कल 25/09/ 2023 के दिन किए जाने वाली एकादशी का व्रत जो कि गलत है शास्त्रो के हिसाब से ...जिससे व्रत करने वाले की आसुरी शक्ति तो बढ़ती है* एवं देवताओ को भी दिव्यशक्ति नहीं मिल पा रही है...... *एक बात मैं और बता दूं आप सब लोगों को.. की सही शास्त्रों के हिसाब से जो भी हम धार्मिक कार्य करते हैं व्रत - उपवास या कोई भी अनुष्ठान उससे देवताओं की शक्ति बढ़ती है* > *और वही दिव्य शक्ति से देवता हमें फिर आशीर्वाद प्रदान करते हैं. और शास्त्र के विरुद्ध कार्य करने से उसकी नकारात्मकता का या क्रोध का भोग हमें ही भुगतना पड़ता है*

> *कलियुग में सब लोग मोहित हो कर दशमी विद्धा एकादशी का , व्रत करेंगे इसीलिए दुनिया में अशांति बनी रहेगी।*

> *आप सभी को सीता माता की दुख भरी जीवन की कथा अवश्य जाननी चाहिए*

> जब सीता जी को लक्ष्मण जी वाल्मीकि ऋषि के आश्रम में छोड़ कर आए थे तब सीता जी ने वाल्मीकि ऋषि से पूछा कि हे ऋषिवर मैंने जीवन में कभी पाप नहीं किया पतिव्रता रही... पति की सेवा की फिर भी मेरे जीवन में इतने सारे कष्ट क्यों आए ❓❓तब बाल्मीकि जी ने सीता जी को जवाब दिया था कि आपने कभी *पूर्व जन्म में दशमी विद्धा एकादशी का व्रत किया था* उसी दिन भगवान की पूजा की थी *उससे पुण्य नहीं पाप बढे उसी का परिणाम है कि आपको यह कष्ट झेलना पड़ा ।*
> *पुराणों में लिखा है कि दशमी विद्धा एकादशी का व्रत करने से धन और पुत्र का विनाश होता है ।* { कल सोमवार के दिन का व्रत बिल्कुल भी ना करें }

> *कल 25 सितंबर 2023, सोमवार के दिन पड़ने वाली परिवर्तिनी एकादशी का व्रत दशमी विद्धा अशुद्ध आसुरी शक्ति को बढ़ाने वाली है* इसीलिए कल के दिन एकादशी का व्रत कदापि शास्त्र सम्मत नहीं है ....इसलिए सभी को  *एकादशी व्रत परसों 26 तारीख मंगलवार को करना चाहिए* पुराणों में स्पष्ट मत मिलता है कि अगर दशमी विद्धा एकादशी हो दूसरे दिन सूर्योदय से पहले एकादशी समाप्त हो रही हो तो द्वादशी के दिन एकादशी का व्रत करके त्रयोदशी को पारण करना चाहिए ।"

What is the meaning of this viddha mentioned in this message, and is this story true of fake? Is there an actual reason for site Mata to end up in forest.

Comment: Can you add the English translation of the message? That will help visitor to understand it better and then address it correctly?

Comment: If there is prevalence of dashami (aka.dashami vedha) during Suryodhaya kalaa(at the time of sunrise) in case of some non Vaishnavas/ arunodhaya kalaa(3 or 4 ghatikas(1 ghatika=24 mins) prior sunrise ) in case of Vaishnavas, then the ekadashi is said to be viddha otherwise it is shuddha.
Presence of Dwadashi the next day is another pivotal consideration .  So what needs to be compromised/takes precedence  , depends on the combinations arrived out of Ekadashi - Dwadashi pair.

Comment: It is usually worked out by a Jyotish karta, based on certain texts like nirnaya sindu, dharma sindu etc .Furthermore timezone differences could compound the complexity of the logistics.There could be some related threads in HSE on this

Comment: So one has to do ekadashi on second day that is on dwadashi ? Or is it right to do it on that day itself.

Comment: I don't know how the translation will look like if I do it with Google.. but one can translate on that.

Comment: It is customary to break the ekadashi vrat on dwadashi day , but If there no prevalence of dwadashi the next day , then some non Vaishnavas may (compromise) fast during viddha ekadashi and break it on triyodashi .. Although  ekadashi takes precedence  over any other karma, in  case of Vaishnavas, I'm not sure whether they would agree with viddha.
Your post startles those who fast on viddha ekadashi. It says such fasts empower asura sampathi..But It doesnt clearly   mention the Padma purana reference/( questionable authenticity).

Comment: Calculations involves more nuances / references ) so. It is customary to get the timings  from an almanac . Only a jyotish karta can properly ans . this Q. with references .what needs to be done could be regional/sectarian.. Also it differs for sanyasi/grihastha